# Why not put .exe in C:\Windows\System32

Tags: windows

From `youtube-dl`'s README:

> Windows users can download an `.exe` file and place it in any location on their PATH except for `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32` (e.g. do not put in `C:\Windows\System32`).

<strike>I've been doing this for sometime. Haven't noticed any problems. So why not do this?</strike>

Actually I put these small `.exe`s in `C:\Windows\` when I cant be bothered messing with the path, but I'm still curious.

Is there any better directory to put them that is on the path by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it very bad practice.  Your own exe files and apps should go into Program Data or other neutral folder.

Second, Windows 10 and above (all that is in support now) do not permit non-certified files / apps to be installed into System32. That is, System32 is very highly secured.

Older systems (notably XP) permitted this and then problems arose when converting to Windows 8 or 10 and above.

Not using system32 will prevent problems over the medium, long term.

Best to heed the advice and not try to do this.

Comment: "Why? Because you shouldn't."

Comment: I'm hearing `C:\Windows\` is still fine. very bad practice, but it cut's corners